# How to install practnlp tools

Tags: python

How to install `practnlptools` in windows as there is no installation guidance in pypi? It would be very helpful also to know how to use `srl tagger` in there.

Comment: [The github repository has instructions](https://github.com/biplab-iitb/practNLPTools)

Comment: i didnt found any instruction ,if you know plzz help me